# how to disable ctrl+c and ctrl+v in Google Cloud Shell so that it is available for emacs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a Google Cloud instance via a Google Chrome ssh.cloud.google.com window on a Mac laptop (English UK keyboard) and I am used to using Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v in emacs-nw for browsing the buffer.

Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v have a different associated value in Google Cloud Shell, how can I disable this behavior and free up Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v for use in my terminal emacs?

Any ideas if this is a matter of moving away from the browser-based ssh connection and using something else?

Answer (score 1):

In Cloud Shell if you click on the little cogwheel/wrench (Terminal Settings) then go to Terminal Preferences > Copy Settings you can make some changes to copy/paste behaviour. That might be what you are looking for.

If not, you can also integrate the SDK into your local terminal following this link:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos

Try SSHing into a machine after setting it up in your terminal and see if the behaviour is the one you desire.

If that doesn't work, then you can try using some program (i think you could do it directly in Mac settings if i'm not mistaken) to change the behaviour of the shortcuts/key combinations.

I'm actually curious if this works for you, so please. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but with visual block mode in vim (Ctrl+v).

Answering your last question of moving away: Yes, by using it locally with `gcloud alpha cloud-shell` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/cloud-shell/))