# Emacs cannot open files in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Starting from last week, Emacs stop working in my Google cloud shell.

emacs test.py will show an empty file. Other editor works. Please see the screenshot below,

1. cat test.py; showing the source code.

[image]

2. "emacs test.py" shows empty screen.

[image]

I tried to remove the .emacs file and didn't help.

Any idea is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: can you precisely explain the issue you are facing , it will help to troubleshoot.

Comment: I edited my question with some screenshots. Thank you for answering.

Comment: can you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676565/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: unfortunately not. the link is about ctrl+c/ctrl+v shortcut and my problem is about emacs doesn't load fie. I tried with all combinations in "Terminal Preference" -> "Copy Settings", and no luck. Thank you for answering.